# Facebook fql.query always an empty result

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I'm writing an app to query insights for several dozen applications; no matter which of these **insights table** queries I try, I always get an empty result set. No errors. Other tables (eg page, application,) do work fine.  Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

//WORKS:

```
$q = 'SELECT app_id, api_key, canvas_name, display_name FROM application WHERE app_id="111"';
```

//DOESN'T WORK:

```
$q = "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id='111' AND metric='page_active_users' AND period='604800' AND end_time='1318615472'";
```

//CODE:

```
require_once '../../scg_common/facebook/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '111', 
    'secret' => '222', 'cookie' => true, 
    ));
$facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->getSignedRequest();

$params = array( 
    'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $q, 
//'callback' => null, 'format' => '', 'access_token' => '',
    );

try{
    $result = $facebook->api($params);   }
catch(Exception $o){
    var_dump($o);  }

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Here's FB test page:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the examples listed on the documentation yet? I mean the exact string?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

If those don't work, then it might be because you don't have the required permission, which is read_insights.

Let me know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter end_time needs to be a valid PST midnight timestamp (per the documentation). My own testing shows the helper function end_time_date() does not work, so you need to pass in the timestamp. Once I fixed that, I started getting query results.

Here are some related bugs:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228141840589755

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232510993491615